# How to print acronyms of glossaries into a table?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, tabularx

for now I am using a tabularx table to print acronyms manually. But I want to use the style of my table with glossaries and acronyms: `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mystyle]`

The table so far:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l @{\hspace{1.5em}=\hspace{1em}}X}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Abk.}} & \multicolumn{1}{@{}X}{\textbf{Bedeutung}}\\%
  \midrule
  %
  LED       & Light-Emitting Diode                  \\%
  VCC       & positive Versorgungsspannung          \\%
  GND       & Ground, negative Versorgungsspannung  \\[0.3ex]%
  \bottomrule%
\end{tabularx}%
```

How would the code of the corresponding style look like? The acronyms will be defined like this:

```
\newacronym{led}{LED}{Light-Emitting Diode}
\newacronym{vcc}{VCC}{positive Versorgungsspannung}
\newacronym{gnd}{GND}{Ground, negative Versorgungsspannung}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can tell `tabularx` doesn't work in a glossary style due to the way the `tabularx` environment processes its contents. However it's possible to achieve the same effect without using `tabularx`. The following example requires the latest version of `glossaries` (v4.01 at time of writing):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}% (for comparison)
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{led}{LED}{Light-Emitting Diode}
\newacronym{vcc}{VCC}{positive Versorgungsspannung}
\newacronym{gnd}{GND}{Ground, negative Versorgungsspannung}

\newlength\maxlength
\newlength\thislength

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {% start of glossary
   % Find maximum width of the first column:
    \setlength{\maxlength}{0pt}%
    \forglsentries[\currentglossary]{\thislabel}%
    {%
       \settowidth{\thislength}{\glsentryshort{\thislabel}}%
       \ifdim\thislength>\maxlength
         \setlength{\maxlength}{\thislength}%
       \fi
    }%
    % Now calculate the width of the second column:
    \settowidth{\thislength}{\hspace{1.5em}=\hspace{1em}}%
    \setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\linewidth-\maxlength-\thislength-2\tabcolsep}%
    % Start the tabular environment
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{1.5em}=\hspace{1em}}p{\glsdescwidth}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Abk.}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\textbf{Bedeutung}}\\%
    \midrule
  }%
  {% end of glossary
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}%
  }%
  % Header has been incorporated into \begin{theglossary}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  % Don't do anything between letter groups
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  % Set display for each the acronym entry
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glsentryshort{##1}}% short form
    &
    \glsentrylong{##1}% long form
    \\% end of row
  }%
  % No sub-entries, so \subglossentry doesn't need redefining
}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{led}, \gls{vcc}, \gls{gnd}.

Next use: \gls{led}, \gls{vcc}, \gls{gnd}.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mystyle]

Compare with:

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l @{\hspace{1.5em}=\hspace{1em}}X}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Abk.}} &
\multicolumn{1}{@{}X}{\textbf{Bedeutung}}\\%
  \midrule
  %
  LED       & Light-Emitting Diode                  \\%
  VCC       & positive Versorgungsspannung          \\%
  GND       & Ground, negative Versorgungsspannung  \\[0.3ex]%
  \bottomrule%
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting document]

Note that the acronyms have been sorted alphabetically. If you want them in order of definition you need to use the `sort=def` package option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using MiKTeX 2.9.4813, how do I update to the latest version of glossaries? The package manager only shows "packaged 2013-07-29".

Comment: @shyd I don't know how quickly MiKTeX picks up on package updates. It is possible to do a [manual installation](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html) by downloading [glossaries.tds.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries.tds.zip) from CTAN and unpacking it to your TEXMF tree.

Comment: That's it! Your solution works like a charm! Thanks for everything!