# Create new glossaries style with tabularx

Tags: glossaries, tabularx

I'm using the [glossaries package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries?lang=en) and I'm trying to create my own style for printing the glossary. Specifically, I'd like my glossary to appear in a particularly formatted tabularx table. I've been trying to refer to the documentation, but they don't go into that much detail concerning this and the only other resource I could find was [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145607/118293) which now appears to be out of date as even the provided answer doesn't work for me.

Ultimately, what I have in my MWE below fails with a misplaced \noalign issue. Can anyone show me a way to create the glossary using the table format I'm trying to achieve?

**Minimum (non-)Working Example**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}      % Provides coloring for tables and text
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Customized table formatting
\usepackage{environ}        % Used to define custom table environment
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% Define table related commands and properties
\definecolor{greyblue}{rgb}{0.6353,0.6863,0.7686} % Define a color used in the tables
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces} % Used for making a row bold
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax} \clearrow % Used for clearing a row formatting
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\centering\arraybackslash}X} % Centered column, input is relative width of page
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % Left-aligned column, input is relative width of page
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X} % Left-aligned column, input is relative width of page

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossarystyle{docstyle}
{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {%
        \table[!htbp]
        \centering
        \rowcolors{2}{black!5}{black!15}
        \tabularx{\linewidth}{C{0.25}|L{0.75}<{\clearrow}}%
        \hline
        \rowcolor{greyblue} \setrow{\bfseries} % Make the header row bold and colored grey-blue
    }{
        \hline
        \endtabularx
        \caption{Abbreviations}
        \label{tbl:abbrev}
        \endtable
    }
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    % Don't do anything between letter groups
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    % Set display for each the acronym entry
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glsentryshort{##1}}% short form
        &
        \glsentrylong{##1}% long form
        \\% end of row
    }%
}

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{Alphabet}

\begin{document}
    \gls{ABC}
    \gls{ABC}

    \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=docstyle]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around, I found an answer that works for me. It turns out the problem with the above code is the `\hline` in the closing environment. If this is removed, the problem is solved and the table is created nicely. However, This means I don't get the line below my table like I want.

To get the table formatted precisely how I wanted, I had to use the `environ` package. This allows me to create a nice table environment that works how I want, and that table environment can be used to define the glossary style. Below is a MWE that works precisely as I wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}      % Provides coloring for tables and text
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Customized table formatting
\usepackage{environ}        % Used to define custom table environment
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% Define table related commands and properties
\definecolor{greyblue}{rgb}{0.6353,0.6863,0.7686} % Define a color used in the tables
\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces} % Used for making a row bold
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax} \clearrow % Used for clearing a row formatting
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\centering\arraybackslash}X} % Centered column, input is relative width of page
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % Left-aligned column, input is relative width of page
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\rowmac\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X} % Left-aligned column, input is relative width of page

\makenoidxglossaries


\NewEnviron{doctable}[4]{%
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \rowcolors{2}{black!5}{black!15}
        \begin{tabularx}{#3\linewidth}{#4<{\clearrow}}%
            \hline
            \rowcolor{greyblue} \setrow{\bfseries} % Make the header row bold and colored grey-blue
            \BODY
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{#2}
        \label{#1}
    \end{table}
}

\newglossarystyle{docstyle}
{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {%
        \doctable
        {tbl:abbrev}
        {Abbreviations}
        {1} { L{0.2}|L{0.8} }
        Abbreviation & Description \\
    }{
        \enddoctable
    }
    \renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
    % Don't do anything between letter groups
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    % Set display for each the acronym entry
    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \glstarget{##1}{\glsentryshort{##1}}% short form
        &
        \glsentrylong{##1}% long form
        \\% end of row
    }%
}

\newacronym{ABC}{ABC}{Alphabet}
\newacronym{GHI}{GHI}{test}
\newacronym{DEF}{DEF}{Some other acronym}

\begin{document}
    \gls{ABC}
    \gls{ABC}
    \gls{DEF}

    \printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=docstyle]
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]